# Expectation value of $r$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, atomic-physics, hydrogen

I am looking for an analytical expression for $$\langle r\rangle = \int dr r^2 R_{n'l'} r R_{nl}$$ where $R_{nl}$ are the radial wave functions, defined as

$$R_{nl}(r)=N_{{nl}}\,r^{{l}}\,e^{{-{\frac  {1}{2}}\gamma r^{2}}}\;L_{{{\frac  {1}{2}}(n-l)}}^{{(l+{\frac  {1}{2}})}}(\gamma r^{2}).$$

The function ${\displaystyle L_{k}^{(\alpha )}(\gamma r^{2})}$ is a generalized Laguerre polynomial. In my case $l,l' \in [0,2]$.

Comment: “Expectation value” refers to the case where $n=n’$ and $l=l’$. Are you looking for the more general matrix element?

Comment: What is $N_{nl}$?

Comment: Does [this](http://www.eng.fsu.edu/~dommelen/quantum/style_a/nt_rsexp.html) answer your question?

Comment: @Tesseract It’s the normalization constant necessary to make $\langle 1 \rangle = 1$.

Comment: oh I am sorry - I refer to the case $n' \not n$

Comment: What system are those the radial wavefunctions for? Not the hydrogen atom.

Comment: I am calculating this for the deuteron - But I am using a harmonic osc. single particle basis

Comment: I think the best you’ll be able to do is express it as a sum (with a finite number of terms) by writing $L$ as an [explicit polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials#Explicit_examples_and_properties_of_the_generalized_Laguerre_polynomials).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Wolfram Functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/LaguerreL3/21/02/01/) site has the following integral which has the form of these matrix elements:

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty &t^{\alpha-1}e^{-pt}L_m^\lambda(pt)L_n^\beta(pt)\,dt=\\
&\frac{p^{-\alpha}\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(n-\alpha+\beta+1)\Gamma(m+\lambda+1)}{m!\,n!\,\Gamma(1-\alpha+\beta)\Gamma(\lambda+1)}{}_3F_2(-m,\alpha,\alpha-\beta;-n+\alpha-\beta,\lambda+1;1)
\end{align}$$

where $F$ is a [generalized hypergeometric function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html).

You just need to let $t=r^2$.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me a lot